# MediaStyle notification updates

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm changing an existing application to use MediaStyle notifications to provide lock screen music information and transport controls in Android 5.0. It seems, however, that updating such notifications isn't working as expected. The following code snippet generates notifications each time a button is pressed, incrementing a counter displayed in the notification title:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {    
    private int serial;
    private TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }

    public void buttonClick(final View view) {
        final Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Title " + serial)
            .setContentText("Text")
            .setContentInfo("Info")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setStyle(new Notification.MediaStyle())
            .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
            nm.notify(1, builder.build());

            text.setText("Serial = " + serial);

            serial++;
    }
}
```

The problems are:

- When executed in the emulator running 5.0, the notification text in the notification drawer or lock screen is out of sync with the serial displayed in the TextView. If MediaStyle is **not** set, notifications have correct numbering in the notification drawer, but not in the lock screen.
- The MediaStyle notification is displayed correctly in the lock screen, until it's viewed in the notification drawer for the first time. After that, it's not displayed as a MediaStyle notification in the lock screen anymore (but not exactly like a standard, non-MediaStyle notification). Notably, buttons added with `addAction()` are not displayed anymore, until the emulator is restarted.

So I suspect I'm doing something very wrong (either that, or the Android image running on the emulator is broken, but that seems less likely). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the emulator was broken after all. The notification behavior, including updating icons added with `addAction()`, title and info updates, and notifications in lock screen after being seen in the drawer, is correct in a real device (a Nexus 5 running 5.0). At the time this answer was written, however, the problems still happened in the emulator provided with the API 21 SDK, and no updates were available.